# How do I implement an address location bar (bread crumb control) similar to that in Windows Vista's File Explorer?

Tags: wpf, windows-vista, controls

The explorer control in Windows Vista is very handy and I would like to be able to incorporate it in an application written in WPF. I've been unable to find a *stock control* that is part of the Framework. This application is being specifically developed for Windows Vista and therefore, having the same look and feel as the OS is desirable.

One could use the [Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.openfiledialog.aspx), but the problem with that is that it looks nothing like Vista's so it sticks out like a sore thumb.

**Any thoughts on a good implementation would be most helpful**. I would like to stay away from Third Party components if possible, but am definitely open to all suggestions.

Comment: Not sure how the title correlates to the message...are you looking for an explorer "bread crumb" control or a way to use the Vista style common dialogs (or both)?

Comment: I'm looking for the "native" way to show the Vista explorer control in a WPF application. Currently, it looks like the options might be p/invoke or go with third party.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't yet tried it but look at [VistaBridge](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms756482.aspx)... It gives you all the Vista look dialog boxes!

Comment: Looks like the VistaBridge code has been updated. This approach works for me. It's a little messy, but seems to be a nice transition into what Win7 might provide. http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/VistaBridge

Comment: At the moment, VistaBridge is best choice comaparing to others!

Answer (score 6):

[Actipro](http://blog.actiprosoftware.com/post/First-Look-Breadcrumb-for-WPF.aspx) makes a really good WPF breadcrumb control. There's also an [open source WPF breadcrumb control](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/tree/WPFBreadcrumbBar.aspx) that I might actually give a try.

Answer (score 1):

There is a replacement for the Microsoft.Win32 file dialogs on my blog that gives you the Vista look without the complexity of VistaBridge and is also backward compatible with XP.

http://www.nbdtech.com/blog/archive/2008/07/15/Vista-style-open-and-save-dialogs-with-WPF-without-using.aspx

Answer (score 1):

At the risk of sounding self-serving, the best Breadcrumb control for WPF you can find is here:

http://www.teraque.com/Products/Explorer-Chrome-Suite

I've spent a year trying to reverse engineer the Window's Vista control because none of the off-the-shelf products provided the right look-and-feel.  You will run into the limitations of all of the suggestions above sooner or later.  And, having been through it myself, I can tell you that trying to embark on developing the controls yourself will take you months.  The oddities surrounding the overflow logic alone will be enough to eat up two months just to get it right.

Good luck.  If there's anything I can answer for you, please feel free to contact me.

Donald Roy Airey

Donald.Roy.Airey@teraque.com

Answer (score -1):

If you are coding for the .net Framework 3.5, calling for the common dialog should display the correct Vista era dialog.

---

Sorry, appears I was mistaken. In previous projects, I was using [this library](http://www.ookii.org/download.ashx?id=VistaDialogs) to call the Vista dialogs.

Comment: Have you tried it? The control displayed is an XP looking control.

Comment: I just did and I forgot I used a library last time I needed these. Updated answer.